# Why is Rails ActiveRelation.update_all updating a different set of records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got a weird case of `ActiveRecord_Relation` magic doing something unintended. Given the following:

```rb
comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
# select only the original commenter's comments that match two scenarios
related_comments = comment.where(something: params[:something)
  .union(comment.where(something_else: params[:something_else]))
  .where(user_id: comment.user_id)

related_comments.count
#=> 4

related_comments.update_all(receive_notifications: true)
#=> SQL (3.9ms)  UPDATE "comments" SET "receive_notifications" = 't'
#=> WHERE "comments"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 11]] [sql_query]
#=> 12
```

From the looks of it, `.update_all` is running a single SQL query that is updating all comments with a `user_id` of 11. The `.where(user_id: 11)` was technically the last query, but shouldn't it be running a SQL query for only the relations of `related_comments`?

I have a workaround where I could do this, but it would require two SQL queries and seems overly cumbersome than necessary:

```rb
comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
# same as above
related_comment_ids = comment.where(something: params[:something)
  .union(comment.where(something_else: params[:something_else]))
  .where(user_id: comment.user_id).pluck(:id)
#=> [12, 14, 17, 18]

Comment.where(id: related_comment_ids).update_all(receive_notifications: true)
#=> SQL (5.7ms)  UPDATE "comments" SET "receive_notifications" = 't'
#=> WHERE "comments"."id" IN (18, 14, 17, 12) [sql_query]
#=> 4
```

Comment: What is your version of rails?